# Prisma Transactions Cross Modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, domain-driven-design, prisma

### Problem

I was trying to implement a clean prisma transaction architecture with a DDD architecture.
My problem is that i want to be able to perform `transactions` cross different modules without need to pass the `prisma` transaction client to each repository
ie:

```js
// repository layer
@injectable()
export class UserRepository{
  constructor(@inject(PrismaClient) private prisma: PrismaClient)

  save(user: IUser): Promise<User>{
     return this.prisma.user.create({data: user});
  }
}

@injectable()
export class OrderRepository{
  constructor(@inject(PrismaClient) private prisma: PrismaClient)
  
  save(order: IOrder): Promise<Order>{
    return this.prisma.order.create({data: order});
  }
}
```

```js
// service layer
export class UserService{
  constructor(@inject(UserRepository) private userRepo: UserRepository)

  create(request: CreateUserRequest){
    return this.userRepo.save(request);
  }
}

export class OrderService{
  constructor(@inject(OrderRepository) private orderRepo: OrderRepository)
  
  create(request: CreateOrderRequest){
    return this.orderRepo.save(request);
  }
}
```

```js
// controller layer
export UserController{
   constructor(
    @inject(UserService) private userService: UserService,
    @inject(OrderService) private orderService: OrderService
   ){}

  placeOrder(
    userRequest: CreateUserRequest,
    orderRequest: CreateOrderRequest
  ){
    // perform transaction, if any fails go with rollback
    // !THIS ACTUALLY DOESN'T WORK
    prisma.$transaction([
       await this.userService.create(userRequest),
       await this.orderService.create(orderRequest)
    ])
  }
}
```

I want to figure out a clean way to achieve this, has anyone faced a similar problem before?

Thank you all!

Comment: If you are passing a PrismaClient instance in all the different modules and then performing a transaction, does it work? Or did you get an error?

Comment: Hi @NurulSundarani, thanks for answering, what do you mean exactly? I provide a PrismaClient in each repository via `singleton`, inside of each i can perform transactions, but i would like to do it from a top level module using the service

Answer (score 1):

Your `UserRepository.save` and `OrderRepository.save`, should return `PrismaPromise`s instead of a `Promise`(https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#the-transaction-api)

Also, when you `await` the promise returned by `UserRepository.save` you are passing a `User` not a `PrismaPromise<User>` which the `$transaction` expects.

To fix it, fix the typing from the repositories methods as commented above and then you should be able to do a transaction by inverting the order on which you await:

```
await prisma.$transaction([
   this.userService.create(userRequest),
   this.orderService.create(orderRequest)
])
```

Comment: IMHO, this solutions does not play well with DDD, as it implies leaking Prisma objects all across the domain layer. However, the OP seems to be ok with being coupled to Prisma, as the repositories are already returning directly Prisma entities